# Enable/Disable TolsStripMenuItem Buttons in Inherited Form based on Rights & Role

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-3.0

I have a Base Form, with 5 Buttons. After that I inherit UserMaster Form from this base form, so I got all controls in UserMasterForm.  I access all controls on Inherited form y this code…

```
base.toolStripSave.Click += new EventHandler(toolStripSave_Click);
```

Now I want to enable\Disable Certain buttons based Role & Rights to specific user.
For this my Role Master Form look like.. Here You can see that I Have given Roles EDIT & PRINT for this UserMaster Form

So Now how to disable `ADD/DELETE/VIEW` buttons in `USERMASTER` Form.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're looking for. Enabling/Disabling buttons is `base.toolStripSave.Enabled = true/false`.

Comment: Consult your favorite C# language book about virtual methods.

Comment: got d solution !!!!!!! BTW thnx...